# Hoard of the Dragon Queen hatchery cave layout

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, battle-map, hoard-of-the-dragon-queen

I'm running *Hoard of The Dragon Queen* for some friends and have hit a bit of a roadblock in map building with the dragon hatchery.  The map

> has two staircases at the end of area 3 leading to areas 8 and 9, meaning that the cave can split off three ways.

While I can take a guess as to how I'm supposed to lay out the mushrooms I'd hate to get the layout wrong as I've heard that

> this encounter is very lethal.  While I have faith in my friends to clear out any encounter I set they tend to approach traps like lemmings.

The question is:

> **are the mushrooms in the centre of area 3 with the paths leading around the walls of the cave or are the paths referred to the ones that lead to areas 8 and 9?**

I know this seems like kind of a obvious question but with not much free time this week to put everything together I don't want to rush and slip up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot access areas 8 and 9 from area 3. Indeed, the staircase from 8 to 9 is below the hallway from 3 to 4. Area 3 is carpeted with fungi and the two paths lead from the staircase (2-3) to the hallway.

Comment: Thanks for the help, can't believe I didn't notice the path was underground.